# How to write a selector for an element with a Class that has a $ sign

Tags: android, selenium, xpath, appium

I'm working on mobile test automation. Basically I'm trying to select a new date in the android emulator using APPIUM with Eclipse (HELIOS) with JAVA. The class name for the time picker is:

`android.widget.RadialTimePickerView$RadialPickerTouchHelper`

As you can there is dollar sign($). If I use the following syntax.

```
List timeButtons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.RadialTimePickerView$RadialPickerTouchHelper"));
```

I get an error message invalid XPATH/CSS selector.

Comment: Use single quotes then, and the $ will not be interpreted.

Comment: Facing the exact same issue. were you able to get a working solution for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is not valid. There is no element `android.widget.RadialTimePickerView$RadialPickerTouchHelper`. You want something like

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='android.widget.RadialTimePickerView$RadialPickerTouchHelper']"));
```

You will want to replace the `DIV` portion with whatever the element is that contains that class.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the element using classname, store it in a List and access it using either its index or some attribute.

```
List <WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.classname("android.widget.RadialTimePickerView$RadialPickerTouchHelper"))
```

After this, iterate the list and perform the action